# New to Combine; dataTaskPublisher doesn't seem to execute

Tags: swift, combine

I am fairly inexperienced with Combine, so I could be making a simple mistake in the following code.  For some reason, it seems that the dataTaskPublisher isn't even executing.  Could someone tell me why?

```
import Foundation
import Combine

enum GitHubAPIError: Error, LocalizedError {
    case urlError(URLError)
    case responseError(Int)
    case decodingError(DecodingError)
    case genericError
    
    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
            case .urlError(let error):
            return error.localizedDescription
            case .decodingError(let error):
            return error.localizedDescription
            case .responseError(let status):
            return "Bad response code: \(status)"
            case .genericError:
            return "An unknown error has occurred"
        }
    }
}

struct User: Codable {
    let login: String
    let url: String
}

private var vmCancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

class NetworkManager {
    
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    private let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    private let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    var dataTaskPublisherSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    private init() {}
    
    private let baseURL = "https://api.github.com"
    
    func fetchFollowers(for userID: String) -> Future<[User], GitHubAPIError> {
        print(" In NetworkManager -> fetchFollowers(for: \(userID))")
        return Future<[User], GitHubAPIError> {[unowned self] promise in
            guard let url = URL(string: self.baseURL + "/users/" + userID + "/followers") else {
                return promise(.failure(.urlError(URLError(URLError.unsupportedURL))))
            }
            print(" In NetworkManager -> fetchFollowers -> URL is \(url.absoluteString)")
            
            dataTaskPublisherSubscription = urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .print()
                .tryMap { (data, response) -> Data in
                    print(" In NetworkManager -> fetchFollowers -> dataTaskPublisher -> inside try map")
                    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                            print(" In NetworkManager -> fetchFollowers -> dataTaskPublisher -> inside try map -> throwing an error  -> status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                        }
                        throw GitHubAPIError.responseError((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 500)   
                    }
                    print(" In NetworkManager -> fetchFollowers -> dataTaskPublisher -> inside try map -> data received")
                    
                    return data
                }
                .decode(type: User.self, decoder: jsonDecoder)
                .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
                    print(" In NetworkManager -> fetchFollowers -> dataTaskPublisher -> inside sink receive completion...")
                    if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                        switch error {
                            case let urlError as URLError:
                            promise(.failure(.urlError(urlError)))
                            case let decodingError as DecodingError:
                            promise(.failure(.decodingError(decodingError)))
                            case let apiError as GitHubAPIError:
                            promise(.failure(apiError))
                            default:
                            promise(.failure(.genericError))
                        }
                    }
                }, receiveValue: {
                    promise(.success([$0])) 
                    self.dataTaskPublisherSubscription?.cancel()
                })
        }
    }
}

class SearchUserViewModel {
    let networkManagerInstance = NetworkManager.shared
    var followers: [User] = []
    
    func fetchFollowers(for userID: String) {
        print(" In SearchUserViewModel -> fetchFollowers(for: \(userID))")
        networkManagerInstance.fetchFollowers(for: userID)
            .print()
            .sink { completion in
                print(" In SearchUserViewModel -> sink completion...")
                switch completion {
                    case .failure(let err):
                    print(" In SearchUserViewModel -> case failure -> Error is \(err.localizedDescription)")
                    case .finished:
                    print(" In SearchUserViewModel -> case finished -> Finished")
                }
            }
            receiveValue: { [weak self] followers in
                print(" In SearchUserViewModel -> receiveValue completion")
                self?.followers = followers
                print(" In SearchUserViewModel -> receiveValue completion -> self?.followers contains \(self?.followers.count ?? 0) followers")
            }
        .store(in: &vmCancellable)
        
        sleep(1)
    }
    
}

let vm = SearchUserViewModel()
vm.fetchFollowers(for: "sallen0400A")
```

All I ever see in the console is that it's printing out the URL, such as:
 URL is https://api.github.com/users/sallen0400/followers

However, nothing happens after that.

As a side note, I'm keeping a reference to the URLSession in the NetworkManager as I was under the impression that the cause of this issue might be that the session is going out of scope.  But, this solution doesn't seem to be valid.

It seems that only when I added a 1 second sleep in the `SearchUserViewModel`'s `fetchFollowers` method, then it works.  But I don't get why.  Something is being deallocated prematurely, but I'm not sure how to tell what that is.

Why?

Comment: That’s a lot of code. Could you condense it a bit to just show the key parts.

Comment: Can you explain why you are wrapping a data task published in a future?

Comment: @matt To be honest, I was looking at code snippets trying to figure out how to use the dataTaskPublisher and this was the type of example I saw most often.  So, I decided to go with it.

Comment: I think the gist of it is that you need to create a subscription to the dataTaskPublisher which determines whether it succeeded or failed.  Then you can pass a success/failure via the future.

Comment: No, I'm not following. A data task publisher essentially _is_ a future. You could wrap an old fashioned URL Session data task with a resume call in a future. But wrapping a data task publisher in a future is like wrapping a future in a future. It just seems silly (to me, at least).

Comment: @matt You could be totally correct.  I'm not doubting that.  But I have seen this done by several other developers.  Here's an example:
https://github.com/alfianlosari/CombineFetchAPICompleted

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a thing to do, especially if you don't know why you're doing. To learn combine, you might want to peruse my book: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/

Comment: I ran your code in a playground and got a lot more than a simple note about which URL it was calling.